# Android Studio will not recognize Google Glass, however ADB will

Tags: android, adb, google-glass

I have a problem with my google glass'.

It will not register in android studio as a device, but when I run "adb devices" in terminal it finds the device and list it as "device".

Android studio says "please configure Android SDK". I have everything installed, API 19 Glass Development kit, API 19 in general, Google usb driver, etc.

Compile Sdk Version points to API 19 aswell, 
build tools version 23.0.3. 
Library respository:  jcenter, flatDir {         dirs 'prebuilt-libs'     }

My gradle is pointing the right way:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 repositories {
    jcenter()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'prebuilt-libs'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion "Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Preview:19"
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.thinknick.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

I'm at ends here, I have tried reinstalling Android studio, restarting ADB, restarting the computer, change USB ports, re-plug the device, other USB ports, etc.

The envoirnment is windows 10 64-bit. The cable I know to work, because it works on a colleagues mac.

Comment: Do you run Android studio in ubuntu...?

Comment: No, windows 10.. Sorry, forgot that detail

Comment: Did you try to assemble and install from the command line using the gradle wrapper?

Comment: No. I have no idea how to do this, google search is coming up a bit short.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, and I'm afraid it was too obvious for me too see for several hours. I ran Android studio as administrator, and it runs perfectly now.

*walk of shame*